# Black lines on object in solid mode

Tags: modeling

Black lines are on object in solid mode. In rendered mode they stay as well. How can i get rid of them?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Strangely enough, it looks like you extruded some vertices, leaving a group of interior, stray (hidden) edges. Hiding some of the outside faces revealed them:

[image: Edges]

Selecting and deleting them helps, but turning on the Face Orientation overlay shows your Normals (face directions) are a bit wonky. I don't know if it's contributing to your viewport anomalies as well, but it's worth taking care of:

[image: Faces]

However, this isn't just a case where we can easily recalculate them outside or inside, because on the other side of the model, there are 2 un-joined edge loops that will screw up the calculations (I don't know if this is intentionally "left open" or not - after recalculating the normals you can delete the faces again if you need). Select the 2 "rings", right click and select "Bridge edge loops" to close in the gap:

[image: Loops]

Once they are joined, you can now select the whole mesh in edit mode and select `Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside` to get all your faces pointing the way they're supposed to:

[image: Normals]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your model in *Wireframe Mode*, there is a possibility, that some edges are copied and then the result can be like that. You can also press <kbd>2</kbd> and try to delete these edges. Since you have used a *Mirror Modifier*, it is possible that two edges are at the same place and thus you get that result.

Comment: Looks like not. I tried merging vertices by distance - same result. I attached the file.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have 1 big N-gon with edges stretching across that do not form faces. You could fix this manually by deleting the big face and forming new ones with all the edges.